# writing and reading value from aerospike using golang

Tags: aerospike

I'm trying to put a (key,value) in aerospike

that it's value is: ("mykey",3).

is this the correct technique?

because i cannot fetch it...

```
    key, err := as.NewKey("namespace", "set","mykey")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    exists, err := client.Exists(Policy, key)
    if exists {
        // Read a record
        record, err := client.Get(Policy, key)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        var newval = 3

    }
    bin1 := as.NewBin("bin1", newval )
    // Write a record
    err = client.PutBins(WritePolicy, key, bin1)
```

Comment: Do you actually have a namespace called 'namespace' in your cluster?

Comment: it is just a test but yes